# Custom audio encoder for flash player

Tags: actionscript-3, mp4, aac

It seems like the only option for recording h264/aac videos with flash is to use Wowza and use the aac transcoder. What options are there for encoding aac audio right inside flash player before sending through the `Netstream`? Would be possible to extract raw audio from a `Microphone` by listening to the `SampleDataEvent`, encoding that audio how you want, then sending it through the `Netstream` with the `send` method? Would you have to manually rejoin the audio with the video then?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will do exactly what you want, but you could check out [FlashyWrappers](http://www.rainbowcreatures.com/product_flashywrappers.php) which allows you to encode video in Flash.